# Replace mosquitto.conf file with bbappend?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I have a layer meta-test where I have created a mosquitto_%.bbappend for customizing the default mosquitto.conf file which is created by the meta-openembedded layer's recipe.
My bbappend file looks like this:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"  
SRC_URI += "file://mosquitto.conf"
```

The image builds without error but the mosquitto.conf is not replaced. What I have observed is the above process replaces mosquitto.conf only if it present in any of the main layers but since the mosquitto_1.5.1.bb file only installs this, and since this file is not present in any layers,how do I overwrite this file? This file gets generated in /etc/mosquitto directory. This is the bitbake file I want to overwrite: http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-connectivity/mosquitto/mosquitto_1.5.1.bb?h=thud

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to Nayfe's answer I want to add this. I solved it by the task do_install_append where I have made some changes compared to the meta-openembedded's mosquitto recipe. I have moved my mosquitto.conf from the working directory to the destination directory which replaces the original conf file.

```
 do_install_append() {

     install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/mosquitto
     install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/mosquitto.conf \
                ${D}${sysconfdir}/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to put your customized `mosquitto.conf` file here:

```
meta-test
  |_ recipes-connectivity
       |_ mosquitto
            |_ mosquitto_%.bbappend
            |_ files
                 |_ mosquitto.conf
```

Comment: I do not have a recipes-connectivity directory, rather I have kept those files exactly in the same way as you have but inside recipes-core directory. Do I need to create this directory, I will try this out

Comment: I kept inside the directory as you mentioned but no changes